# TestNG tests not wait until previous finishes

Tags: xml, maven, testng

I have problem with tests, that I want to run them subsequently, but some of them starts before another finishes. How Can I prevent that?

My config:

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng-install.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng-config.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng-tests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

**testng-install.xml**

```
<suite name="install" verbose="10" parallel="false">

<test name="install" parallel="false">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ac.web.it.install.server.InstallEnvironmentTest" />
        <class name="com.ac.web.it.install.backend.InstallBackendTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

**testng-config.xml**

```
<suite name="config" verbose="10" parallel="false">

<test name="config" parallel="false">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ac.web.it.install.config.ConfigTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I want to finish all tests in `testng-install` and only then start tests in `testng-config`.